# Best way to represent object views (summary, detail, full etc) in Spring based REST service

Tags: spring, rest

I am working on a REST service which uses Spring 4.x. As per a requirement I have to produce several different views out of same object. Sample URIs:

To get full details of a location service: `/services/locations/{id}/?q=view:full`
To get summary of a location service: `/services/locations/{id}/?q=view:summary`

I have thought of two solutions for such problem:
1. Create different objects for different views. 
2. Create same object, but filter out the fields based on some configuration (shown below)
location_summary_fields = field1, field2
location_detail_fields = field1, field2, field3

Could someone help me to understand what could be an ideal solution? I am not aware of any standard practice followed for this kind of problems.

Thanks,
NN

Comment: Why not just make a different service methods to query the data for each specific view you need. I don't see a point in duplicating fields into different data transfer objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this article on how google gson uses annotations to convert a Java Object representation to a json format : http://www.javacreed.com/gson-annotations-example/

Since you want two different representations for the same object you could roll your own

```
toJson method as follows :
a) Annotate each field of you model with either @Summary, @Detail or @All
b) Implement a toJson() method that returns a json representation by examining the annotations for the fields and appropriately using them

If you need an XML representation same thing, except you would have a toXML().
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I need to design my own annotations `@Summary`, `@Detail` etc; right? I am not much into GSON, hence a little confused.

Comment: thats right. for each field of the single POJO that you want represented as either summary or detail or both, you would annotate them as such. i provided the GSON example so that you could see how GSON is doing something exactly like that (ability to name the elements in the json independent of the field names through an annotation). its really fairly simple to write this annotation.

Comment: also this way of doing things - one model object - multiple views is a best practice since it is represented by the MV portion of the MVC pattern. The MVC pattern states that you usually want to have one model and different views of the same model servicing different clients. MVC pattern - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best option is to use separate POJOs for different views. It's a lot easier to document it (for example when you use some automated tools like [Swagger](http://swagger.wordnik.com/)). Also you've to remember that your application will change after some time, and then having one common POJO could make troubles - then you'll need to add one field to one service and don't expose it through another.